# Intellisense using phonegap

Tags: iphone, intellisense, cordova

I need to develop an app for iphone using phonegap
I want to have a drop down box which has the capacity of intellisense.
Like when i type 'A' in the dropdown box, all the data elements listed with 'A' should be a part of drop down. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be able to create an autocomplete drop down box using something like jQuery -- for which there is already a plugin to do that: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

You could write it from scratch but there are already a lot of autocomplete JavaScript libraries.